# How to easily duplicate a Windows Form in Visual Studio? (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, forms, if-statement, rename, copy-paste

how to create a new form in code but coping another form and making that a new one

I was thing on somthing like this

```
private sub CreateDesktop()
     If What ever username logged in it would only create one if its a new user Then
     Copy.form
     paste.form as form2
     form2.show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Its quite vague what you are looking for. Perhaps rephrase the question a bit to make it more understandable?

Comment: how to create a new form in code but coping another form and making that a new one

Comment: You can always make new instance of that form how is that difficult?

Comment: How do i use new instance code? (i looked it up but i need a clearer view of it)

Comment: New instance of code? That is not what I meant. New instance would be of the form itself with the same code and functions.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is to copy a forms code and events and functions to create a similar form. Is that so? If yes then do you want to create it in the same project or a different one?

Comment: the reason i need is to create a form that has certain items but only gets created with a new "log in" account but i dont want to manually create a million forms for each account P.S each account will start with new form with certain starting items but they configure the look and icon and stuff for there personal account, (so i want a form created for that specific person)

Comment: Well that is not possible as per your understanding of it. What you can do is create a general layout form. with all elements required. Then as per the user or type of user make controls visible or invisible as required.

Comment: Instead create a settings either as database table or xml file or whatever means that contains the preferences for each user, like icon visibility, icon location, form's location etc. Then when the user logs in, load that user's preferences.

Answer (score -1):

Instead create a settings either as database table or xml file or whatever means that contains the preferences for each user, like icon visibility, icon location, form's location etc. Then when the user logs in, load that user's preferences.